# How do you unsplit all split panes in tmux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, gnu-screen

In short, I'm looking for the tmux equivalent to the gnu screen `'only'` command (<kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd>).

In gnu screen I will often split the window any number of times, then when I'm done and want to go back to one, single, unsplit, window, I just do the <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>Q</kbd> command.

I can't seem to figure this out in tmux.  I don't want `kill-pane -a` because I don't want anything to be terminated, I just want things to go back into the background where they were before I split the screen.  I also don't want to go through the `break-pane`/`join-pane` nonsense because I don't want the pane to be divorced into some background window that I can't then split again if I want.

Comment: When you split a pane in `tmux`, a new shell is started in the new pane. For the new pane to "go away", you would have to end that shell process. That shell did not exist before you split the pane, so there's nowhere for it to "go back" to.  You may however zoom a pane with `<prefix>+Z`. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Kusalananda Oh, I see what you mean.  So, say I have one window where I'm ssh'ed into one server and running something, then another window ssh'ed into another server running something else, how do I then split it so that I can see both?

Comment: The easiest way to get rid of a pane is just to terminate whatever is running in it, in many cases it will just be a shell that you exit just like you would exit any other shell.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to close all panes except the one selected, e.g. if you inadvertently pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>"</kbd>, you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> `:kill-pane -a`. Change selected pane using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> (or use arrow key instead of <kbd>o</kbd>)

If you don't want to a pane and kill the command that run in it, select the pane, and convert it to a window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> `:break-pane -t :`